# Android Studio Preview is not showing ListView examples

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, preview

I'm new to app development, so maybe I just made an obvious mistake. 
However my problem is, like I mentioned in the title, my preview is not showing the ListView examples (Picture 1 show what I want the preview to show), but when I add an ArrayList and start it on the emulator every thing is displayed correctly.

1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4uON.png

2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hneo.png

3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0jf3.jpg

4 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pczx.jpg

Comment: As first, try to update Android Studio

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, just updated form 3.5 to 3.6. Unfortunately no improvements.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout XML (activity_main.xml), you can add the tools:listitem attribute to the ListView to specify a layout to show in the preview. Like this...

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_something"
    ... />
```

Just replace 'item_something' with the name of the layout you want to use for each item.

PS. When you're in 'Design' mode rather than editing the XML, look for the attributes with a small spanner icon to the left. There are other 'tools' attributes you can use for similar things.

Comment: If `tools:listitem` not set it set automatically default preview

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Just tried it out, but I´m still wondering what i did wrong or wich of my setting is wrong because normally this preview of the ListView example ( Picture 1) should just appear automatically or am i getting something wrong there?